# Unresolved Reference on recyclerView not working?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, pusher

I've been building a stock application with push notifications that I found online. { [Link](https://pusher.com/tutorials/stocks-push-notifications-kotlin) }. I've had several issues that I have came across, that I have found answers to and fixed... However I cannot figure out what the issue is here. This is the problem from my MainActivity

```
private fun setupRecyclerView() {
    with(recyclerView){
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        adapter = mAdapter
        addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
    }
}
```

What am I overlooking?
The issue **with** says "not enough information to infer type variable R."
followed by (recyclerView) "unresolved reference: recyclerView" although it's stated in my layout as @+id/recyclerView

Layout Below

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjuest the code as follows.

```
private val pusher = Pusher("PUSHER_KEY", options)
private val channel = pusher.subscribe("stock-channel")
private lateinit var recyclerView : RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    setupPrefs()
    pusher.connect()
    setupRecyclerView()
    setupPusherChannels()
    setupPushNotifications()
}
```

Now it will work for you.
The issue was you are using an old tutorial that use syntatic sugar for view id's.